# Paging with jsonRest in Ehancedgrid in dojo

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

i have 100000 records in database...i have to display 50 at a time in enhanced grid when i scroll down next request goes to server and get next 50 like wise ......

i came across that this can be achieved by jsonRestStore....i tried with that but i am not getting that..how to use jsonRest for this purpose ????..plz sugggest me answer

my code is

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/lang", "dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
    "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Search","dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter",
    "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination","dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore", 
    "dojo/store/JsonRest","dijit/form/Button","dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojox/grid/cells/dijit",
    "dojo/domReady!" 
], function(lang,EnhancedGrid,Search,Filter,Pagination,ItemFileWriteStore,JsonRest,Button,xhr, dom, domConst, JSON, on) {

    xhr("//myipaddress/GridExample/string", {
        handleAs : "json"
    }).then(function(dataa){

        /*  domConst.place("<p>response: <code>" + JSON.stringify(dataa) + "</code></p>", "output"); */

        /* domConst.place("<p>response: <code>" + JSON.stringify(dataa) + "</code></p>", "output"); */

        var mydata=dataa;
        var yourStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
            data: {
                identifier: "sno",
                /* items: mydata.aa */
                items:mydata
            }
        });

        grid = new EnhancedGrid({
            id:'grid',
            store : yourStore,
            structure : layout,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            plugins: {
                search:true,
                pagination: {
                    pageSizes: ["50","100","500","1000"],
                    description: true,
                    sizeSwitch: true,
                    pageStepper: true,
                    gotoButton: true,
                    maxPageStep: 2,
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                filter: {
                    closeFilterbarButton: true,
                    ruleCount: 5,
                    itemsName: "rows"
                }
            }
        });
        grid.placeAt("myGrid");
        grid.startup();                 

    }, function(err) {
        alert("error");
    }, function(evt) {
    });

    var id=100000;
    var addbutton = new Button({
        onClick: function (){
            id++;
            /* alert(dojox.grid.scroller.firstVisibleRow);
            alert(dojox.grid.scroller.lastVisibleRow); */
            console.log(arguments);
            grid.store.newItem({
                sno:id,
                sname:'san',
                salary:'25000'
            });
            store.save();
            grid.render();
        }
    }, "addRow");

    var removebutton = new Button({
        onClick: function (){
            var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
            alert(items);

            if(items.length){                
                dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
                    if(selectedItem !== null){                        
                        store.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                        store.save();
                    } 
                }); 
            }
            grid.render();
        }            
    }, "removeRow");  

    var updatebutton = new Button({
        onClick: function (){
        }            
    }, "updateRow");  

    var store1 = new JsonRest({
        target: "http://localhost:7080/GridExample/string"
    });

    store.get(3).then(function(item){
        alert(item);
    });                                   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must have found answer to your question by now. But to help others, You haven't tied your JsonRest store (store1) to grid.

Here is example code that does this:

```
    //jsonstore
    var jsonStore = new dojo.store.Cache(new dojo.store.JsonRest({
        target : "http://localhost:7080/GridExample/string",
        idProperty : "id"
    }), dojo.store.Memory({
        idProperty : "id"
    }));

    grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        store : dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({
            objectStore : jsonStore
        }),
        id: "grid_id",
        structure : layout,
        rowSelector : '20px',
        selectionMode : "single",
        clientSort : true,
        plugins : {
            selector : true,
            /**nestedSorting : true,**/
            pagination : {
                defaultPageSize : 20,
                pageSizes : [ 20, 50, 100, "All" ],
                description : true, // display the current position 
                sizeSwitch : true, // display the page length menu 
                pageStepper : true, // display the page navigation choices 
                gotoButton : true, // go to page button   
                /*page step to be displayed*/
                maxPageStep : 4,
                /*position of the pagination bar*/
                position : "bottom"
            }

        }
    }, "search_results_grid"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
```